# Grabbing the text value of an XML node + Nokogiri and xpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have built a rake file to insert all of the information I grab about a certain  into my database.  This is all working, but the values for my keys are not being populated with any data.  Am I possibly making my at_xpath calls incorrectly? I'll post an example below --

```
information = {
            "street_address" => property.at_xpath("/Address/AddressLine1/text()"),
            "city" => property.at_xpath("/Address/City/text()"),
            "zipcode" => property.at_xpath("/Address/PostalCode/text()"),
            "short_description" => property.at_xpath("/Information/ShortDescription/text()"),
            "long_description" => property.at_xpath("Information/LongDescription/text()"),
            "rent" => property.at_xpath("/Information/Rents/StandardRent/text()"),
            "application_fee" => property.at_xpath("/Fee/ApplicationFee/text()"),
            "bedrooms" => property.at_xpath("/Floorplan/Room[@RoomType='Bedroom']/Count/text()"),
            "bathrooms" => property.at_xpath("/Floorplan/Room[@RoomType='Bathroom']/Count/text()"),
            "bathrooms" => property.at_xpath("/ILS_Unit/Availability/VacancyClass/text()")
        }
```

I know everything is working perfectly aside from putting the data into the actual value spaces in the hash listed above.  I also know that nokogiri and xpath are working properly as I have narrowed down the number of s down from 33,000+ to 1,068.

Any guidance would be super appreciated! Thank you :)

========================= UPDATE ============================

I thought seeing the whole loop might help add clarity --

```
doc.xpath("//Property/PropertyID/Identification[@OrganizationName='northsteppe']").each do |property|

        # GATHER EACH PROPERTY'S INFORMATION
        information = {
            "street_address" => property.at_xpath("/Address/AddressLine1/text()"),
            "city" => property.at_xpath("/Address/City/text()"),
            "zipcode" => property.at_xpath("/Address/PostalCode/text()"),
            "short_description" => property.at_xpath("/Information/ShortDescription/text()"),
            "long_description" => property.at_xpath("Information/LongDescription/text()"),
            "rent" => property.at_xpath("/Information/Rents/StandardRent/text()"),
            "application_fee" => property.at_xpath("/Fee/ApplicationFee/text()"),
            "bedrooms" => property.at_xpath("/Floorplan/Room[@RoomType='Bedroom']/Count/text()"),
            "bathrooms" => property.at_xpath("/Floorplan/Room[@RoomType='Bathroom']/Count/text()"),
            "bathrooms" => property.at_xpath("/ILS_Unit/Availability/VacancyClass/text()")
        }


        # CREATE NEW PROPERTY WITH INFORMATION HASH CREATED ABOVE
        if Property.create!(information)
            puts "yay!"
        else
            puts "oh no! this sucks!"
        end

    end # ENDS XPATH EACH LOOP
```

============================ ANOTHER UPDATE ==========================

so I tried swapping out the "/text()" at the end of each at_xpath path with "/inner_text()" and received the following error --

rake aborted!
Invalid expression: /Address/AddressLine1/inner_text()

I then tried switching my "at_xpath" calls to "at_css" calls and doing something like --

```
"street_address" => property.at_css(".AddressLine1").text
```

but recieved the following error --

rake aborted!
undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass

============================= UPDATE TO SHOW XML ===========================

```
<Property IDValue="642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8">
  <PropertyID>
    <Identification IDValue="642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8" OrganizationName="northsteppe" IDType="property"/>
    <Identification IDValue="6e1e61523972d5f0e260e3d38eb488337424f21e" OrganizationName="northsteppe" IDType="Company"/>
    <MarketingName>Spacious House Central Campus OSU, available fall</MarketingName>
    <WebSite>http://northsteppe.appfolio.com/listings/listings/642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8</WebSite>
    <Address AddressType="property">
      <Description>Address of Available Listing</Description>
      <AddressLine1>1689 N 4th St </AddressLine1>
      <City>Columbus</City>
      <State>OH</State>
      <PostalCode>43201</PostalCode>
      <Country>US</Country>
    </Address>
    <Phone PhoneType="office">
      <PhoneNumber>(614) 299-4110</PhoneNumber>
    </Phone>
    <Email>northsteppe.nsr@gmail.com</Email>
  </PropertyID>
  <ILS_Identification ILS_IdentificationType="Apartment" RentalType="Market Rate">
    <Latitude>39.997694</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-82.99903</Longitude>
    <LastUpdate Month="11" Day="11" Year="2013"/>
  </ILS_Identification>
  <Information>
    <StructureType>Standard</StructureType>
    <UnitCount>1</UnitCount>
    <ShortDescription>Spacious House Central Campus OSU, available fall</ShortDescription>
    <LongDescription>One of our favorites! This great house is perfect for students or a single family. With huge living and sleeping rooms, there is plenty of space. The kitchen is totally modernized with new appliances, and the bathroom has been updated. Natural woodwork and brick accents are seen within the house, and the decorative mantles. Ceiling fans and mini-blinds are included, as well as a FREE stack washer and dryer. The front and side deck. On site parking available.</LongDescription>
    <Rents>
      <StandardRent>2000.00</StandardRent>
    </Rents>
    <PropertyAvailabilityURL>http://northsteppe.appfolio.com/listings/listings/642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8</PropertyAvailabilityURL>
  </Information>
  <Fee>
    <ProrateType>Standard</ProrateType>
    <LateType>Standard</LateType>
    <LatePercent>0</LatePercent>
    <LateMinFee>0</LateMinFee>
    <LateFeePerDay>0</LateFeePerDay>
    <NonRefundableHoldFee>0</NonRefundableHoldFee>
    <AdminFee>0</AdminFee>
    <ApplicationFee>30.00</ApplicationFee>
    <BrokerFee>0</BrokerFee>
  </Fee>
  <Deposit DepositType="Security Deposit">
    <Amount AmountType="Actual">
      <ValueRange Exact="2000.00" Currency="USD"/>
    </Amount>
  </Deposit>
  <Policy>
    <Pet Allowed="false"/>
  </Policy>
  <Phase IDValue="642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8">
    <Name/>
    <Description/>
    <UnitCount>1</UnitCount>
    <RentableUnits>1</RentableUnits>
    <TotalSquareFeet>0</TotalSquareFeet>
    <RentableSquareFeet>0</RentableSquareFeet>
  </Phase>
  <Building IDValue="642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8">
    <Name/>
    <Description/>
    <UnitCount>1</UnitCount>
    <SquareFeet>0</SquareFeet>
  </Building>
  <Floorplan IDValue="642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8">
    <Name/>
    <UnitCount>1</UnitCount>
    <Room RoomType="Bedroom">
      <Count>4</Count>
      <Comment/>
    </Room>
    <Room RoomType="Bathroom">
      <Count>1</Count>
      <Comment/>
    </Room>
    <SquareFeet Min="0" Max="0"/>
    <MarketRent Min="2000" Max="2000"/>
    <EffectiveRent Min="2000" Max="2000"/>
  </Floorplan>
  <ILS_Unit IDValue="642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8">
    <Units>
      <Unit>
        <Identification IDValue="642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8" OrganizationName="UL Portfolio"/>
        <MarketingName>Spacious House Central Campus OSU, available fall</MarketingName>
        <UnitBedrooms>4</UnitBedrooms>
        <UnitBathrooms>1.0</UnitBathrooms>
        <MinSquareFeet>0</MinSquareFeet>
        <MaxSquareFeet>0</MaxSquareFeet>
        <SquareFootType>internal</SquareFootType>
        <UnitRent>2000.00</UnitRent>
        <MarketRent>2000.00</MarketRent>
        <Address AddressType="property">
          <AddressLine1>1689 N 4th St </AddressLine1>
          <City>Columbus</City>
          <PostalCode>43201</PostalCode>
          <Country>US</Country>
        </Address>
      </Unit>
    </Units>
    <Availability>
      <VacateDate Month="7" Day="23" Year="2014"/>
      <VacancyClass>Unoccupied</VacancyClass>
      <MadeReadyDate Month="7" Day="23" Year="2014"/>
    </Availability>
    <Amenity AmenityType="Other">
      <Description>All new stainless steel appliances!  Refinished hardwood floors</Description>
    </Amenity>
    <Amenity AmenityType="Other">
      <Description>Ceramic tile</Description>
    </Amenity>
    <Amenity AmenityType="Other">
      <Description>Ceiling fans</Description>
    </Amenity>
    <Amenity AmenityType="Other">
      <Description>Wrap-around porch</Description>
    </Amenity>
    <Amenity AmenityType="Dryer">
      <Description>Free Washer and Dryer</Description>
    </Amenity>
    <Amenity AmenityType="Washer">
      <Description>Free Washer and Dryer</Description>
    </Amenity>
    <Amenity AmenityType="Other">
      <Description>off-street parking available</Description>
    </Amenity>
  </ILS_Unit>
  <File Active="true" FileID="820982141">
    <FileType>Photo</FileType>
    <Description>Unit Photo</Description>
    <Name/>
    <Caption/>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Src>http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/northsteppe/images/31077069-6e81-4373-8a89-508c57585543/medium.jpg</Src>
    <Width>360</Width>
    <Height>300</Height>
    <Rank>1</Rank>
  </File>
  <File Active="true" FileID="820982145">
    <FileType>Photo</FileType>
    <Description>Unit Photo</Description>
    <Name/>
    <Caption/>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Src>http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/northsteppe/images/84e1be40-96fd-4717-b75d-09b39231a762/medium.jpg</Src>
    <Width>350</Width>
    <Height>265</Height>
    <Rank>2</Rank>
  </File>
  <File Active="true" FileID="820982149">
    <FileType>Photo</FileType>
    <Description>Unit Photo</Description>
    <Name/>
    <Caption/>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Src>http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/northsteppe/images/cd419635-c37f-4676-a43e-c72671a2a748/medium.jpg</Src>
    <Width>350</Width>
    <Height>265</Height>
    <Rank>3</Rank>
  </File>
  <File Active="true" FileID="820982152">
    <FileType>Photo</FileType>
    <Description>Unit Photo</Description>
    <Name/>
    <Caption/>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Src>http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/northsteppe/images/6b68dbd5-2cde-477c-99d7-3ca33f03cce8/medium.jpg</Src>
    <Width>350</Width>
    <Height>265</Height>
    <Rank>4</Rank>
  </File>
  <File Active="true" FileID="820982155">
    <FileType>Photo</FileType>
    <Description>Unit Photo</Description>
    <Name/>
    <Caption/>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Src>http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/northsteppe/images/17b6c7c0-686c-4e46-865b-11d80744354a/medium.jpg</Src>
    <Width>350</Width>
    <Height>265</Height>
    <Rank>5</Rank>
  </File>
  <File Active="true" FileID="820982157">
    <FileType>Photo</FileType>
    <Description>Unit Photo</Description>
    <Name/>
    <Caption/>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Src>http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/northsteppe/images/3545ac8b-471f-404a-94b2-fcd00dd16e25/medium.jpg</Src>
    <Width>350</Width>
    <Height>265</Height>
    <Rank>6</Rank>
  </File>
  <File Active="true" FileID="820982160">
    <FileType>Photo</FileType>
    <Description>Unit Photo</Description>
    <Name/>
    <Caption/>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Src>http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/northsteppe/images/02471172-2183-4bf1-a3d7-33415f902c1c/medium.jpg</Src>
    <Width>350</Width>
    <Height>265</Height>
    <Rank>7</Rank>
  </File>
</Property>
```

Comment: Show your automated tests. Take the / out of `at_xpath("/ILS_Unit`, because it means "go back to the root of the document". And does `at_xpath()` need a `.to_s`, to turn an XML text node back into a string?

Comment: @Philip - I have removed the /s and then added .to_s to the end of each at_path query and rerun my rake task, still with no data being submitted.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: If you add `p information` do you have your hash of variables? And if the create! fails, what is in its exception?

Comment: @philip - when I add "puts information" it outputs the hash with the key but not the value.

Comment: We have no idea if your XPaths are correct because you didn't show us the XML you're parsing. 

Off-hand though, how you're doing it is wrong, plus, even if it worked, it'd be inefficient.

Comment: `puts` will concatenate all the values together as strings. (Calling `.to_s` on each one.) Use `p` to see the raw data.

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: @theTinMan - I added an example of one of the XML <Property> nodes at the end of my question.

Comment: @philip - using "p information" yields the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first XPath is too deep. It returns an Identification where you need a PropertyID. Try this:

```
doc.xpath("//Property/PropertyID[ Identification/@OrganizationName = 'northsteppe' ]").each do |property|
    # GATHER EACH PROPERTY'S INFORMATION
    information = {
        "street_address" => property.at_xpath("Address/AddressLine1/text()").to_s,
        "city" => property.at_xpath("Address/City/text()").to_s,
        "zipcode" => property.at_xpath("Address/PostalCode/text()").to_s
        }
    p information
end
```

Comment: @philip - I LOVE YOU!

Comment: @philip, one more question, so I am able to accurately fill the values for street_address, city, zipcode and short_description (by grabbing the <MarketingName> value.  I now need to grab the other pieces of information that are hanging outside of the <PropertyID> node, would I just make my first call even less deep so that I can use my xpath queries to reach those nodes?

Comment: Now that you have worked it out, look up the `parent` and `ancestor` axes in XPath. It's a complete relational query language, competitive with SQL or Prolog

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you do:

```
doc.xpath("//Property/PropertyID/Identification[@OrganizationName='northsteppe']").each do |property|
```

Then, for your values you do things like:

```
property.at_xpath("/Address/AddressLine1/text()")
```

You can't use `/Address/AddressLine1/text()` relative to `property` with XPath.

Nokogiri will search for `/Address/AddressLine1/text()`, which means, start at the absolute path, which would be starting from the top of the document `/`, find the `Address` node immediately below it, find the `AddressLine1` node under it....

Instead use:

```
Address/AddressLine1/text()
```

Which means search *relative* to `property` and results in the full XPath:

```
//Property/PropertyID/Identification[@OrganizationName='northsteppe']/Address/AddressLine1/text()
```

---

Looking at the XML you added...

The paths you want don't exist. Looking at it in PRY:

```
[16] (pry) main: 0> puts doc.xpath("//Property/PropertyID/Identification[@OrganizationName='northsteppe']").to_xml
<Identification IDValue="642da00e-9be3-4a7c-bd50-66a4f0d70af8" OrganizationName="northsteppe" IDType="property"/><Identification IDValue="6e1e61523972d5f0e260e3d38eb488337424f21e" OrganizationName="northsteppe" IDType="Company"/>
```

Neither of the `property` nodes have children. Only the node for `property` exists, so all the values you're looking for, which are child-nodes, aren't there.

Instead, it looks like you want to find the `Property` node and work downward:

Comment: I did add an example of the XML I'm parsing at the end of the question. When I stripped away the /s in front of each at_xpath query, it just gave "nil" as a value for each key in my hash.  Thank for for the positive direction :)

Comment: So, if I am trying to grab all of the property nodes that have an <Information> node with the OrganizationName = 'northsteppe' and then loop through those property nodes to make my at_path calls, what would the proper method of doing this be?